# How do I find out what needs Microsoft.VC90.CRT.Manifest from .NET client

Tags: visual-c++, manifest, visual-c++-runtime

I have a WPF application that references binaries in a released version of our software. However, it does not build because it cannot locate the Microsoft.VC90.CRT.Manifest in the runtime folder. I know this is an old VC++ 2008 CRT thing. However, I have two questions:

[1] How can I find out what needs the manifest file, I presume there's a bit of a dependency chain at work here? All I reference directly are .NET assemblies.

[2] Is there a way I can install the 2008 CRT stuff so that my project builds without needing to locate the manifest file (i.e. it's get installed and found at a common location - WinSxS?)? I am assuming that we should **not** be distributing this manifest file.

Comment: Hmm, that is not the kind of error you can get while building, since you don't do anything with those DLLs other than copying them.  Certainly from running your program, do distinguish F5 from Build > Build.  The author probably forgot to embed a manifest in the DLL itself, relying on the one embedded in the original C++ EXE file.  Technically fixable, you have to replicate the manifest entry in the manifest of your own EXE.  Using File > Open > File on these binaries is the way to check and copy/paste, RT_MANIFEST node.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I see it as an error when trying to copy files:                   
Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not copy the file "C:\...\Bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest" because it was not found.

Comment: Back to my question, how do I figure out which dll is 'referencing' this manifest file? If referencing is the right term. Do I have to go through all the potential  binaries and look at the Manifest entry?

Comment: Sure, why not.  It is useless knowledge, you know for a fact that one of them has a bad or missing manifest, you might as well assume they all do.  Use File > Open > File on the original EXE that used these DLLs so you can copy/paste the manifest text.  If you don't have this EXE then do talk to the owner of these DLLs, it is certainly better if he fixes them.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in on this. Can you provide some more basic information please, I think I'd appreciate taking a step back? Firstly, what should have happened to the manifest file to have avoided the situation where my application is trying to access it?  What should I do about it? You refer to EXE files in this discussion, but clearly I only reference dlls. Should the dlls have included this manifest or there something else going on here? I feel that the real issue is in the code that is two steps away from my code.

Answer (score -1):

Right, I can provide some answers to my question, even if it's not the full answer.

To work out what required the manifest, I ended up setting my build output level to diagnostic and then searching the log. This revealed the deepest and highest dependency in the chain, but not the references between these.

...

```
1>  bin\x64\Debug\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
1>                  CopyLocal=true
1>                  FusionName=
1>                  HintPath=<path to the reference in my project that pulls in this file (indirectly)>
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=<path to the output folder>\Kitware.VTK.dll < The dll at the bottom of the chain that needs the manifest
1>                  ResolvedFrom=<path to the folder containing the referenced binaries>
1>                  SpecificVersion=False
1>                  Version=7.1.0.1009
```

From this I could see that the Kitware.VTK.dll was causing the CopyLocalFiles error and which of the immediate references was pulling this in. However, I could not see the reference chain that lead to this. I loaded the top level reference (the .dll) into dotPeek and used the assembly dependency graph to examine the reference chain between these two dlls - *NB this worked but was non optimal and the GUI really struggled with the dependency diagram.*

I now need to figure out how to break this chain or if I can embed the manifest in the assembly we control.